# Firebase performance data with big query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, looker-studio, firebase-performance

I want to load firebase performance(performance monitoring) data into big query so that I can create custom visualization on Google data studio.
is it possible to do this with performance monitoring? I am not able to find this in docs anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no export of Firebase Performance Monitoring data.

Comment: @paramjeet It's definitely a valid feature request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for the response, sent the feature request.

Comment: when you say no export, is that just for exporting to BigQuery? Or is there no way at all to access the underlying performance metrics data? (@FrankvanPuffelen maybe you also know)

Answer (score 1):

It's happening now. You can export your firebase performance data in BigQuery for custom queries or reports

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/bigquery-export